# A linear map where any non-zero element will go to non-zero element only

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I want to define a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with the property that any non-zero element in $\mathbb{R}^n$ should go to non-zero element only in $\mathbb{R}$. Only a hint is enough.

Is it possible to define a linear map from $V$ ($n$ dimension) to its field set $F$ with the above property ?

Comment: There is no such map if $n>1$. Also, could you clarify what you mean by "write"?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming $R$ is the real numbers and $n>1$, this is impossible. The reason is that the rank of any such map is $1$, so its nullity is $n-1>0$ by the [Rank-Nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_nullity_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

As Alex said, if $n>1$ this is impossible.  Assume such a map exists. Let $ e_1, e_2\in \Bbb R^n$ be the canonical basis vectors $e_1=(1,0,\dots,0, 0)$ and $e_2=(0,1,\dots,0, 0)$ and $f$ be such a map.

$$f(e_1)=r_1 \ne 0$$
$$f(e_2)=r_2 \ne 0$$

But $f(r_1e_2-r_2e_1)=0$, and $r_1e_2-r_2e_1\ne 0$.